# gradle jar cant find java source

Tags: gradle

I am going through the gradle jar build example at https://guides.gradle.org/building-jvm-libraries/

The java source is not in a default `src/main/java` directory, it's in `org\example\mylib` directory. How can I customise gradle to run `gradle jar` from this directory and compile the java source files to a jar?

The whole directory structure is `\mylib\src\main\java\org\example\mylib`

When I am in that directory, and run `gradle jar` there is a success message but then when I check with `jar -tf build/libs/mylib-0.1.0.jar` all I see is the manifest files. There are no java classes.

If I try and run `gradle jar` in the `\mylib` directory alone, then it fails with error message `Task 'jar' not found in root project`

The build.gradle file is:

`apply plugin: 'java'
 version = '0.1.0'`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the gradle.build:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src\main\java\org\example\mylib']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but now the message `Task 'jar' not found in root project` happens in the `\mylib\src\main\java\org\example\mylib` directory. Basically I figured that the gradle.build has to be in the `\mylib` directory alone, and then it works, but I'd still like to run commands not from the root directory!

Comment: If I understood correctly, changing 'src\main\java\org\example\mylib' to 'mylib\src\main\java\org\example\mylib' may fix the problem

Comment: nope, it says "success" but it still doesn't compile the java class in that directory....